# Problema con driver al conectar Base de datos Apache Derby en Netbeans 17

Tags: derby

Tengo una BD hecha en Derby, pero no puedo conectar a la misma, porque me da error en el Driver. Mi código en la clsConexion es

```
public void crearBD() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
//        String driver = "org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver";
//String myDb = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TEJAM";
//Connection DBconn = DriverManager.getConnection(myDb, "","");
        String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
        //String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
        String dbName = ".\\TEJAMBD\\TEJAM";
        String dbParam = "create=true"; //la base de datos se creará si no existe todavía
        String URLcrearBD = "jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";" + dbParam;
        String cadena;
    try{
      Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
//      Class.forName(driver);
      conector = DriverManager.getConnection(URLcrearBD);
      if (conector!=null){
```

He probado con todos esos driver que hay ahí, pero no conectar, al intentar crear una nueva BD directamente me tira este error
[image: Error al crear DB]

Si intento conectar la BD existente me tira el error
[image: Error al conectar DB]

Esta es la configuración de la Java DB
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En principio conectaba bien, pero no me dejaba ver las tablas de la BD, mi versión Derby era la db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin, pero al actualizar a la db-derby-10.16.1.1-bin me empezó a tirar el error de driver.
El servidor de Apache funciona correctamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Están los JAR en el Classpath? Recuerda además colocar tanto el código como los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles.